# Jade/Pug if else condition usage

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm sending a date to a .jade file from my .js file using `Node.js`. When the `#{date}` field is `false`, it executes the else and print `man` as it's answer. What could be going wrong?

```
if #{date} == false
  | #{date}
else
  | man
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If date is false, do you want to output the string 'man'?
If yes, your if and else statements are the wrong way around...

How about:

```
if date
  = date
else
  | man
```

or even:

```
| #{date ? date : 'man'}
```

or simply:

```
| #{date || 'man'}
```

Answer (score 8):

Within if expression you write plain variable names, without #{...}

```
if date == false
  | #{date}
else
  | man
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement was backwards.  For the syntax, You can use this style to work:

```
p Date:
  if date
    | date
  else
    |  man
```

Its correct that you don't need the `#{}` within expression. I was not able to get the `=` to work, or other ways on the other answers.

**Ternary Style**

For Myself, I too was looking for the ternary operator to do this on one line. I whittled it down to this:

```
p Date: #{(date ? date : "man")}
```

Alternatively, you can use a var, which adds one more line, but is still less lines than OP:

```
- var myDate = (date ? date : "man")
p Date: #{myDate}
```

I was not able to get the following to work, as suggested in another answer.

```
| #{date ? date : 'man'}
```