# Conditional statement in Pug

Tags: html, pug

I have the following use case, In my project I have two different footers. 
Thanks to the suggestion from @sean I tried out a case statement.
This is my template:

```
//- layout.pug
include head

body
    block nav
        include nav

    block content  

    block footer

        case chooseFooter
            when 1
                include footer1
            when 2 
                include footer2        

    block scripts
        script(src='js/index.js')
```

This is the first footer:

```
li
  .footer_contact1

li
  .footer_contact1
```

This is the second footer:

```
ul.boxes
      li
      .footer_contact2

    li
      .footer_contact2
```

And this is the index page calling upon the template:

```
extend includes/layout

append content
    .promo

    ul.boxes
        li
          .boxes__text-wrapper
        li
          .boxes__text-wrapper
        li
          .boxes__text-wrapper
        li
          .boxes__text-wrapper

prepend footer
        - let chooseFooter = 1
```

The problem accords if I choose footer1, I get the following output:

```
<div class="promo">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="boxes">
    <li>
      <div class="boxes__text-wrapper"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="boxes__text-wrapper"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="boxes__text-wrapper"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="boxes__text-wrapper"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<li>
      <div class=".footer_contact1"></div>
 </li>
<li>
      <div class=".footer_contact1"></div>
 </li>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

So the li:s in the first footer get outside the ul, and they should be inside the closing ul.

If I don't use the case code and just do a normal include and insert it after the last li item in the index file and use the following:

```
li
   .boxes__text-wrapper

include includes/footer
```

then the footer1 li items are embedded before the closing ul tag. But then I can't naturally only use one footer.

I hope I am making more sense this time.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with the base `if-else` feature ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744984/jade-pug-if-else-condition-usage

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to pug, so the if statement, would it be implemented in the template, and how is then implemented in the page calling the template?

Could you please provide an example for the template above in the block foot?

Comment: I don't actually use Pug, but I suppose the official documentation has all the explanation you need. It would even be better if you find how to code it with the doc instead of getting the finished solution.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a final solution, just needed to know if the condition should be in the template and how its implemented inte page extending the template

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. AFAIK, the condition should be in the template. As I said, I haven't used pug much, so your bedt solution is looking into the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Set up a [conditional](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) or [case](https://pugjs.org/language/case.html) statement in your template block that checks the value of a variable.

**layout.pug**

```
html
  head
    block head

  body
    nav
    block content
    block footer
      footer
        case whichFooter
          when 1
            p Some footer content
          when 2
            p Some other footer content
          default
            p Some other default footer content
    block scripts
      script(src='/my.js')
      script(src='/pets.js')
```

Then define that variable in your page, and *prepend* it to the appropriate block in the template.

**page.pug**

```
extends layout

append head
  title Page A

append content
  p My page content...

prepend footer
  - let whichFooter = 1
```

That way, you're effectively defining the variable before pug needs it to check the conditional or case statement.

(Also don't forget to nest that `nav` inside the the `body` instead of beside it.)

Comment: My main file has a ul with some li:s. Before the ul tag is closed in the code, I wanted to insert some more li:s, which are in the include of footer1, which only has li:s. I wanted to try out a simple include of footer1.
This works, its closes the ul after the include footer1. But when I tried with my if statement in my main page or your case code in my template, the ul closes before prepending footer1.
Choosing the second footer in my prepend code works fine as it has its own opening ul with embedded li:s.
How do I make footer1 with its li:s embedded inside the first ul block content?

Comment: i forgot to mention that I don't have any actual footer tag, i know, bad practice. But that's also why li:s in footer one are supposed to be part of the first ul.

Comment: Please edit your question or ask a new question with examples of the output code. It's hard to follow what you're describing. As long as the conditional `if` statement is indented at the right level, it should keep tags open

Comment: Sorry, edited the question, hope it makes more sens now :) The second footer works normally, as its in its own ul and is supposed be outside the first ul.

Comment: You can't nest something from one block into content appended into another block.

Comment: I am trying to follow what you just wrote, but please try to explain this further, and is there a solution where I can make my use case work out?